# PSQL: Type coercion for large numerics

Tags: node.js, postgresql

`column_with_very_big_numerics`  is `numeric(30,0)`

```
SELECT
    column_with_very_big_numerics
FROM some_table
```

I am using the `pg` node.js client. I would the result to come back as a numeric. Because this number is so large that I can't use int e.g.

```
SELECT
    column_with_very_big_numerics::int,
FROM some_table
```

This above will throw an error as it is out of range. Is there any way to get around this? What is the largest numeric that PostgreSQL and the `pg` node.js client can return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `column_with_very_big_numerics` to come to you as `NUMERIC`, don't cast it to `int`.

You've written:

```
SELECT
  column_with_very_big_numerics::int
FROM some_table;
```

Instead, just write:

```
SELECT
    column_with_very_big_numerics
FROM some_table;
```

[The largest `integer` (and largest `bigint`) PostgreSQL can represent is in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html). These limits don't apply to `numeric` as it's a different type.

Your client library must understand how to deal with `numeric`; otherwise you'll probably just get the number as a string. You probably need to find an *arbitrary precision decimal floating point* library to work with these numbers if your programming language does not support them natively. E.g. in Java you use `BigDecimal`, a built-in type; in Python you use Python's `decimal` module (automatically supported by psycopg2, IIRC) etc. I don't use Node.js, which it sounds like you are using, so I cannot help you with that.

If node.js's `pg` driver doesn't cope with `numeric` then either (a) write a patch to fix that, or (b) change your schema to avoid `numeric`, using `bigint` and (where necessary for non-integers) fixed-point multipliers.